# How to treat memory leaks using the new AndroidProfiler

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-studio-3.0, leakcanary, android-profiler

I'm trying to learn how to identify and treat memory leaks in my App. I'm reading this [great article](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8), but I'm a bit confused about how to apply that in the new "Android Profiler" tool, that came with Android Studio 3.0.

I'have a test application and LeakCanary is pointing that my App has memory leaks.

In fact, when I run the profiler and press "dump java heap" I can see that there are 4 instances of my MyCollectionActivity and, when I click on these instances, I can see the details:

[image]

But the tool that is shown in the article has options I cannot see in the "Android Profiler":

> I will not go into depth about how to navigate the huge memory heap.
>   Instead I’ll direct your attention to the Analyzer Tasks in the upper
>   right corner of the screenshot below. All you have to do to detect the
>   memory leak introduced in the example above is to check Detect Leaked
>   Activities and then press play to get the leaked activity to show up
>   under Analysis Results.

Where, in the new tool, is, for example, this "Analyzer Tasks" and "Analysis Results" that shows instances that have leaks?

[image]

> If we select the leaked activity we are presented with a Reference
>   Tree where the reference that is keeping the activity alive can be
>   identified. By looking for instances with depth zero we find that the
>   instance mListener located within the location manager is the reason
>   our activity can’t be garbage collected.

That Android Profiler's image doesn't show that Reference Tree too, it shows the reference, but it doesn't seem to be very useful.

Comment: "Where, in the new tool, is, for example, this "Analyzer Tasks" and "Analysis Results" that shows instances that have leaks?" -- AFAIK, it doesn't exist. If you capture a heap dump from code via `Debug.dumpHprofData()`, IIRC, AS 3.0.1 will use the earlier tool that has those panes.

Comment: That  "dumpHprofData" method should be used when OutOfMemoryError occurs? To see who is holding my activity where should I put this call?

Comment: "That "dumpHprofData" method should be used when OutOfMemoryError occurs?" -- probably not, as your environment will be fairly unstable then. "To see who is holding my activity where should I put this call?" -- well, LeakCanary should be telling you that. And it dumps the HPROF data using this call (and I think there's an option for getting its HPROF file, though I forget the details). Otherwise, you might call `dumpHprofData()` in an instrumentation test, after you think that you have set up a leak scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First, you need to **save** the **Heap Dump**. The dump save with extension **hprof**. Check the below-attached image for saving this file.
2. Open the same file in Android Studio, after that, you will be able to see the **Analyser Tasks** option at the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: Don't forge to add .hprof in the end of the file's name -while exporting the heap dump. Ex: test.hprof